# Android replaces certain characters in the filename with ASCII hex value

Tags: android, filenames

I'm creating files in my app with '{' and '}' in the filename (e.g. {foo}.xml).  However, the special characters are being replaced with the ASCII hex values instead (i.e. {foo}.xml is created as %7Bfoo%7D.xml).  Any thoughts on how to get around this and have it actually create '{foo}.xml' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new File("/sdcard/{file name}.xml").createNewFile()` successfully creates a file with name "{file name}.xml" on SD card in my case.

`new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/{file name}.xml").createNewFile()` successfully creates such file in private app files area.

I checked that all right using ADB shell and file explorer.

Comment: Thank you!  I was leaving the file creation up to the XML Transformer, which mangled the filename a bit.  I was able to get around it by first creating an empty file with your answer and then writing to it.